# VerifyError: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred on addItem to ArrayCollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, stack-overflow

This error occurred when one of the "developer rows" box in the ColorDataGrid is selected which in turn calls the updateDeveloper() method in ExtractProjectPopup.mxml that is shown below.

```
public function updateDeveloper():void
{
    developerIndexArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    var devObject:Object = new Object();
    var ObjectString:String = developerIndexArray.toString();
    if(developerGrid.selectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        var developer:ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow = this.developerRows.getItemAt(developerGrid.selectedIndex) as ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow;
        developer.isPartOfProject = ! developer.isPartOfProject;
        if(developer.isPartOfProject)
        {   
        devObject.index = developerGrid.selectedIndex;
        viewResumeButton.visible = true;
        developerIndexArray.addItem(devObject);     
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently using Flex SDK 3.6 and I'm aware of the known [bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-2993) whose workaround (adding trace statements) does not really help in this case. I suspect the overflow happens when I add the object is added to the ArrayCollection but I don't really know why.

There must be some sort of recursion which is forcing the overflow, am I missing something?

Here's the stack trace leading to the overflow:

```
[mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I]  mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]]   {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (mx.collections::ArrayCollection[O] int[I])
60:callproperty getItemAt 1
                   [mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I]  mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]]  {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (Object[A])
64:getlex 7044
                   [mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]] {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (Object[A] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow$[O])
67:astypelate
                   [mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]] {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O])
68:coerce mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow
                   [mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]] {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O])
71:dup
                   [mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O] Object~[A] int[I] int[I] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] String[S] int[I]] {mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp~[O]} (mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O] mpt.vo.extraction::ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow[O])
72:dup

Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.

at mpt.project::ExtractProjectPopUp/__developerGrid_click()
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Judging by the stack I don't even think it gets to `developerIndexArray.addItem`. It appears to be regarding `this.developerRows.getItemAt`. There is also a late binding as noted by `astypelate` that could be creating the recursion as shown by `72:dup`. Although, I can't really know without seeing what the `developerRows` member and `ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow` class really are. Also, your AS3 appears to be a snippet (i.e. it has incompleteness with *mysterious* variables), although you have not described otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, the problem was resolved by adding an empty trace statement after the statement

```
var developer:ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow = this.developerRows.getItemAt(developerGrid.selectedIndex) as ExtractPopUpDeveloperRow;
```

This is not a solution but just a workaround.